# Calling git commit from shell-command results in incorrect log message

Tags: microsoft-windows, hooks, git

I implemented the following to git commit after a file is saved. It works, I think, but the commit message, rather than being empty, is the literal value `''`. This is the case whether or not I have any text in the quotes after the `-m`.

I expect my quoting is wrong - can someone confirm or deny please?

```
  (defun my-after-save-actions ()
    "Used in `after-save-hook'."
    (if (string-match-p (regexp-quote "Journal.org") (buffer-file-name))
        (shell-command "git add Journal.org && git commit --allow-empty-message -m ''")
    )
  )

  (add-hook 'after-save-hook 'my-after-save-actions)
```

Comment: The function seems to be missing a couple of parens. I tried `M-: (shell-command "git add Journal.org && git commit --allow-empty-message -m ''") RET` but I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Possibly a Windows thing :( I don't get the same (undesired) behaviour in WSL.

Comment: Correction: just one paren is missing (and I added it in the edit).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, appears to be a Windows thing. Simply replacing the `-m ''` with `-m \"\"` does the job. Could have sworn I tried that, but I guess not.

Comment: Which shell are you using?